# OmniSharp extension fails to load on Arch VScode

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, archlinux, omnisharp

I've had this problem for a while now, and it's gotten to the point where I can't code like this anymore. I really want to be able to get my .NET core projects running on Arch VScode, and be able to use intellisense and go to function definitions. Whenever OmniSharp tries to load my .NET core Web API Project, I get the following error.

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 9/11/2019, 9:52:34 PM
    Target: /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo

OmniSharp server started with Mono 5.20.1.
    Path: /home/wasiim/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.2/.omnisharp/1.34.2/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 6298

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on arch 0.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Providers.MonoInstanceProvider
        It looks like you have Mono 5.2.0 or greater installed but MSBuild could not be found.
Try installing MSBuild into Mono (e.g. 'sudo apt-get install msbuild') to enable better MSBuild support.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.0 - "/home/wasiim/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.2/.omnisharp/1.34.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/wasiim/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.2/.omnisharp/1.34.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.0 - "/home/wasiim/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.2/.omnisharp/1.34.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            TargetFrameworkRootPath = /usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks
            MSBuildToolsPath = /home/wasiim/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.2/.omnisharp/1.34.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /home/wasiim/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.2/.omnisharp/1.34.2/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /usr/lib/mono/xbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo/demo.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo/demo.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo' on host 4467.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo/demo.csproj'.
/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo/demo.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.  /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo/demo.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x0024e] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext) [0x00103] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x0002d] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x0005e] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00126] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00093] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <4e0a1f1d78cf4c1ebd6f9a3dbcebf3bb>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath) [0x0003f] in <f8463d63e28447fa8b83b5dd1035433b>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath) [0x0000d] in <f8463d63e28447fa8b83b5dd1035433b>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader) [0x00015] in <f8463d63e28447fa8b83b5dd1035433b>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <f8463d63e28447fa8b83b5dd1035433b>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <f8463d63e28447fa8b83b5dd1035433b>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/demo/demo.csproj
```

OmniSharp works perfectly well in console projects. I think this is just a web api thing. Also, there's no .vscode folder.

Comment: Have you checked this https://www.google.com/amp/s/andrewlock.net/the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-web-specified-could-not-be-found/amp/

Comment: @dvitel maybe this seems to apply only to VS because VScode does not generate a global.json file.

Comment: @dvitel I noticed there is no .vscode folder either